# nth-child selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am working with the following svg
[image: Svg]

```js
const selector = document.querySelector('.yAxis g:nth-child(3)');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
  <rect class="boundRect" x="50" y="50" width="1180" height="620" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>
  <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(50px, 50px);">
    <g fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end" class="yAxis">
      <path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M0.5,620.5V0.5"></path>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,620.5)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">0</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,549.531741126106)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">10,000</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,478.56348225221205)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">20,000</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,407.59522337831805)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">30,000</text>
      </g>
      
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to write a query that selects the `2nd <g> element of class="yAxis"`
which is following

```
<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,549.531741126106)">
    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
    <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">10,000</text>
  </g>
```

`const selector = document.querySelector('.yAxis g:nth-child(3)');` is selecting the correct element but why am I passing `3` as `nth-child(3)` value when I am selecting the `2nd` **g** element of `class=yAxis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead of [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) because the `:nth-child` selector will also count the first `path` element:

```js
const selector = document.querySelector('.yAxis g:nth-of-type(2)');
console.log(selector.outerHTML);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
  <rect class="boundRect" x="50" y="50" width="1180" height="620" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>
  <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(50px, 50px);">
    <g fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end" class="yAxis">
      <path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M0.5,620.5V0.5"></path>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,620.5)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">0</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,549.531741126106)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">10,000</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,478.56348225221205)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">20,000</text>
      </g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,407.59522337831805)">
        <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
        <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">30,000</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `path` is first child .
and with `.yAxis g:nth-child(3)` you select 2th `g`
you can use `.yAxis g:nth-of-type(2)`